# Can you read an Ibook on a PC?

Tags: itunes, microsoft-virtual-pc, emulator, creative-commons

Actually this part of a broader aim on my part. I would like to be able to download free stuff from the Itunes web site and run it on my PC - this covers Ibooks (free), podcasts and courses of various kinds.

One of my user groups said it isn't possible. But I have a hunch it should be possible. After all a long time ago you couldn't run PC software on a Mac, but now you can, so...... ideas please.

Comment: Have you actually tried doing this? What stopped you from doing it? Does iTunes only allow this type of content on Macs?

Comment: @BrianTurner tags are specifically meant to describe what the question is _about_, not to attract attention from people who may or may not know about the content of your question. Your question is not about Adobe products, so the Adobe tag doesn't belong. Please read the [About] page for some more info on how it all works.

Comment: @BrianTurner I removed two of my comments regarding tagging as the question was re-tagged and my comments no longer contributed towards finding you an answer.

By "consuming" I mean the the inverse of "aggregating" or "distributing," more simply I mean that the iBooks software is used to read and (in a sense) collect ebooks as opposed to producing or distributing them.

My comments were aiming to emphasize the difference between iBooks (software/application) and ebooks (media). Your original question appeared to imply that you wished to read iBooks, or to "run" ebooks and podcasts.

Answer (score 3):

[iBooks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBooks) uses the industry standard epub, or pdf formats.

Checkout [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) (pronounced caliber), it is a program that runs on Windows/Mac/Linux which is great for managing ebooks.

The Apple store contains DRM, and non DRM encrypted ebooks. It is *possible* to export an ebook from iTunes and read it on your PC or put it on a non apple device (check with the apple license agreement before doing so).

You can not read a DRM encrypted ebook on a non apple device / PC.

Unfortunately calibre can not *buy* books from the Apple Store, you will need to find the books from another source (like amazon).

Comment: I converted your answer to a comment in order to migrate all of the comments under your answer (which is the only way to move comments around), then I un-deleted your answer and deleted the generated comment. Just FYI. All the banter has been moved up to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a thread on this in the [apple support forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3072596?start=45&tstart=0).

The general answer is that you may be able to read the free books (which don't have any DRM), but you won't be able to read those with DRM.